# Can i create an app with React-native, firebase, and node js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-hosting

So i would like to have a **react-native** app and use all the cool features from firebase. Since I'm fairly new to firebase though, I'm curious if and how I could possibly install a **nodejs** environment -which should be hosted by **firebase**- to add some Api features. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can. For hosting your nodes environment, you can use Google Cloud Engine, firebase can only host static content.

Comment: Okay thank you. So would you recommend to combining these two (GCP and Firebase) in one app ?

Comment: this is what google recommends as well.

Firebase for authentication, cloud messaging, file storage, realtime databases. Cloud functions and Cloud Engine for any backend related stuff (APIs for example)

Answer (score 1):

Firebase itself will not execute your Node.js code, but it has integrations with Cloud Functions and Cloud Run, which can be used precisely for that.

I recommend having a look at the documentation, specifically the pages on [serving dynamic content and host microservices using Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).